# Assembly.LoadFrom not loading DLL in a different project

Tags: c#, reflection

I have multiple projects in a given solution.
From ProjectA I pass "myProjectB.dll" as assemblyname to a method call
in ProjectC.

When I execute the following in ProjectC, where assemblyname is "myProjectB.dll"

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyname);
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
       ... my code ...
}
```

I get the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\MyProjectB\bin\Debug\myProjectB.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please let me know how to pass in the assemblyname properly into Assembly.LoadFrom method call.

How can I provide only the project DLL name and be able to go through the solution and identify the full absolute path for that DLL in the solution at run time. Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Is the file physically located in that folder?

Comment: no its not located in that folder.

Comment: Sooooo..... what exactly are you asking? How to load an assembly you don't have? Give it the correct path.

Comment: asawyer.. is it possibly to just provide the project/dll name and be able to locate the full absolute path within the solution?

Comment: If you write the code to do the path search sure, but `Assembly.LoadFrom` needs a correct path.

Comment: If you have both projects in your solution, why are you not just add a reference from one to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the assembly is not located in the exact path as your executable, or in the GAC, you need to give the full path in the LoadFrom method.

For example:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\MyProjectB\bin\Debug\myProjectB.dll");
```

You can also use relative paths:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"..\..\..\MyProjectB\bin\Debug\myProjectB.dll");
```